# IIS7 HTTP Error 503 Event 5002 Application pool disabled automatically Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: iis-7.5, load-balancing, windows-server-2008-r2

I was able to work through this issue, however I wanted to post on here because of how long I had to search to finally figure out the issue.

I had copied an IIS installation from one server to a new one and set up all of the sites. Everything seemed to be working, however one of the applications would fail after very few calls were made to it.

The Event Log shows an Error 5002:

```
Application pool '{appPoolName}' is being automatically disabled due to a series 
of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.
```

I was sent all over my server settings to look at folder permissions and this was not the issue. I was also sent to Microsoft's `Page Not Found` page numerous times to download a Debug Diagnostics tool. *(Not sure this tool exists for 2008 R2)*

[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/03/02/what-is-a-crash-technically-in-asp-net-and-what-to-do-if-it-happens.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to track down [this page](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/failure#005) which pointed me in the direction of the `loadBalancerCapabilities`.

If you are behind a load balancer and it is HTTP aware this setting should be set to `HttpLevel` *(default)*, however if your load balancer is **not** HTTP aware you need to set it to `TcpLevel`.

Also you will want to make sure that your load balancer is not set to filter by Bytes/Packets but by Destination/Session Established. Once I made these changes I fired up the app pool and pounded it with requests and had no more errors.

Also just for search/record the load balancer that I was using was a:

**Syswan Technologies Duolinks SW24 Dual WAN Load Balancer**